# How to add a LFO to filter cutoff using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I found a few results for this, but I'm still coming up short, so I believe it has to be a fundamental issue with my code.

I want to be able to connect a Low Frequency Oscillator to my Filter Cutoff in the Web Audio API, but every attempt at this fails. Eventually, I want to be able to modulate the frequency of this LFO and the amount of modulation to the cutoff. For now, I would simply like to make the damn thing modulate to begin with. Here's the code for a single note (https://github.com/natotthomer/NH-101/blob/master/frontend/util/note.js), and for the live repo (http://natotthomer.com/NH-101/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key problem I can see in your code is that you're not amplifying the LFO before connecting it to the frequency cutoff.  This means you're connecting a value that oscillates between -1 and 1 to detune - and remember, detune is in cents (i.e., 100 cents between "notes").  A range of 2 is going to be barely perceptible, if at all.

Go ahead and create and insert that LFOGain - but it try setting it to, say, 600.  Now your LFO should cause your filter to have a range of an octave in its modulation, and should be audible.

Comment: Ahhh! You're a genius! I knew it had to either be something huge and architectural or miniscule. Glad it was the latter. Thank you very much.